# How can I tell if a wifi printer can print PDF without proprietary drivers?

Tags: pdf, printing, network-printer

The obvious answer would be to check the printer spec sheet and look for Page Description Language (PDL). My problem is that most spec sheets don't explicitly mention PDF, they only mention proprietary formats (like PCL, SPL, UFR, etc.), these need proprietary drivers which I want to avoid. But I have a suspicion I'm missing something.

Most wifi printers manufactured in the last several years are Mopria/AirPrint/WiFi-direct certified, these standards mandate certain PDF or raster formats and those are usually not listed among the supported PDLs of the printer. (I can provide examples of these spec sheets if that helps.)

Do such certified wifi printers support native PDF in general? Or do all recent printers support PDF? Or if PDF is not in the spec sheet, then they really don't support it? Or am I mixing up something about native vs. emulated formats?

Comment: The PDF spec can get pretty complex, I don't think that it is well suited for printers. A lot of printers claim to support PDF, but if you test it (e.g. print a PDF from USB stick) a lot of documents fail to print or the printout looks different than expected. For printers with enough CPU and RAM PostScript may be an option.

Comment: You don't need anything on the printer - use a PDF viewer to print.

Comment: @harrymc: PDF viewers can't talk to printers directly.

Comment: Of course they can print. I do that all the time.

Comment: I know, but that says nothing about what drivers you use and whether the printer natively supports PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on the printer's specs to see if the device supports PDF. Use a search engine if necessary. Are you sure that it can print PCL ? If it can, you can convert the PDF file into PCL using ghostscript. This piece of software can convert to numerous output formats. ghostscript is free software.

An other important point is to known which communication protocols are used over the WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research and even contacting manufacturers, the answer is that it's hard to know because the spec sheets are just incomplete. What seems to be certain is that any printer that supports one of the networked standards mentioned in the question will support at least one or more of the few standard formats. These are PWG, URF, PDF, PCLm (a subset of PDF). So all these printers should work without manufacturer-specific drivers. Whether the standard driverless format of a given model happens to be PDF or one of the others doesn't seem to matter that much to anyone.